# Stopping times of Markov chains

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, stopping-times

I have the following problem:

> Consider a state space $E$ and a Markov chain $X$ on $E$ with transition matrix $Q$ such that for every $x \in E$, $Q(x,x)<1$. Define: $\tau:=\inf\{n\geq 1:X_n\neq X_0\}$.
>
> 1. Show that $\tau$ is a stopping time
> 2. Show that, for every $x\in E$, $\tau<\infty$ $P_x -a.s.$
> 3. Compute the distribution of $\tau$ and that of $X_\tau$ under $P_x$

So for the first point I tried this:
$\tau$ is a stopping time if $\{\tau =n\}$ is $\mathbb{F}_n$-measurable $\forall n$.
Since the Markov chain is based on its natural filtration we know that $\forall n : X_n$ is $\mathbb{F}_n$-measurable.

Define $A:=\{X_n:X_n\neq X_0\}$ and so $\tau = \inf\{n\geq 1: X_n \in A\}$ so I can write 
$\{\tau =n\}= \{X_n \in A\}\bigcap \{X_{n-1} \not\in A\}\bigcap...\bigcap \{X_0 \not\in A\}$
And by this equation we see that $\{\tau =n\}$ is $\mathbb{F}_n$-measurable $\forall n$.

For points 2 and 3 I can't get the meaning of $P_x$-a.s. I think it should be easy since by assumption I have $ Q(x,x)<1$ (which it should implies that there exist an y s.t. $Q(x,y)>0$. But this is only a thought..

Comment: The definition of A seems unsound. You might want to expand it. At the moment, A is a random subset of the *state space*, is this what you mean and, if so, what is A exactly?

Comment: Yes, I want A to be a subset of my statespace and the complement of $X_0$ does it make sense?

Comment: Then define $A=E\setminus\{X_0\}$, this is clearer. Indeed, with this definition, $[X_n\in A]$ is in $F_n$ and you are done. To show that $\tau\lt\infty$ almost surely conditionally on $X_0=x$, one may compute $P[\tau=n\mid X_0=x]$ for every $n$, then check that these probabilities sum to $1$.

Comment: I don't understand really what do you mean with this sum. Could you say me if this other way make sense?
I assume that $\tau = \infty$
Then I can say that $\forall y\in E: P_x(H_y<\infty)=0$ where $H_y=\{n\geq 1: X_n =y\}$ so I can say that X is not irreducible (all states do not communicate) but that's a contradiction since $Q(x,x)<1$

Comment: And for point 3.. What is mean to be the distribution of a stopping time?

Comment: Wow... Which textbook are you following?

Comment: why wow :) no textbook.. that was an exercise-sheet

Comment: "Exercise-sheet" related to some lectures, for which you have some notes, presumably, notes which might define "distribution" and "stopping time" (thus, "wow").

Comment: I don't really see your point. These things were defined but under this form I've never seen it and the definition which I have is not thought for these problems.

Comment: I don't really see your point. Compare "What is mean to be the distribution of a stopping time?" and "These things were defined". To make your question useful (and answerable), you might add the definition you know and why it "is not thought for these problems".

Comment: Ok.. So if I ask for any help means that I really have trouble solving problems and that in my lecture things were not clear. I don't find really nice from you the fact that you are you making fun on my English.

Comment: This is not an English question (and to imagine that I would be making fun of your English requires a seriously biased reading). Once again, please add the definition of the distribution of a stopping time that you know, since you said you know one. (Note that 11+ comments to even formulate what is causing you trouble is **much too much**.)

Comment: I did not say that I have such a definition. I have the definitions of stopping time, of distribution but I really don't have the definition of the distribution for stopping time. I agree with you that 11+ comments are too much.. but I already wrote what I needed in the 5-th line. If I had one I probably had wrote it and asked for more explanations.

Comment: You are not making this easy. If the answer below is not what you are after, then... well, so be it.

Answer (score 2):

From the looong string of comments above, it seems a problem of understanding might be related to the words *distribution of a stopping time*. Let us explain these. To this end, one should consider
a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$, a filtration $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$, and a random variable $S:(\Omega,\mathcal F)\to \mathbb N\cup\{+\infty\}$.

Recall that $S$ has a *distribution*. This is the image of $P$ by $S$, that is, the measure $\mu$ defined by $\mu(M)=P[S\in M]$ for every $M\subseteq\mathbb N\cup\{+\infty\}$. The measure $\mu$ is entirely characterized by the collection of probabilities $\{\mu(\{n\})\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$, or, equivalently, by the collection of probabilities $\{\mu(\{1,2,\ldots,n\})\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$, or, equivalently, by the collection of probabilities $\{\mu(\{n,n+1,\ldots\})\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Furthermore, $S$
is a *stopping time* with respect to $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ if and only if the event $\{S\leqslant n\}$ is in $\mathcal F_n$, for every $n$ in $\mathbb N$. Equivalently, one can ask that the event $\{S=n\}$ is in $\mathcal F_n$, for every $n$ in $\mathbb N$.

Consequently, in the present case, question 1. asks to show that $\{\tau=n\}$ is in $\mathcal F_n$, for every $n$ in $\mathbb N$, for some unspecified (but canonical) filtration $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ I will let you explain, and the first part of question 3. asks to compute $P[\tau=n]$ for every $n$ in $\mathbb N$, or equivalently, $P[\tau\leqslant n]$ for every $n$ in $\mathbb N$, or equivalently, $P[\tau\geqslant n]$ for every $n$ in $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help